# can´t run d3js example for ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, d3.js, ionic-framework

I struggle to run this example
https://github.com/abritopach/ionic2-d3js-example

I install the latest ionic 2 version, npm etc. but if i try to run the app i get an error in browser console.

```
polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'.
1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'tabRoot' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to > the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<super-tabs height="100%">
        <super-tab [ERROR ->][tabRoot]="tab1Root" title="Line Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab2Root" title="Bar C"): ng:///AppModule/TabsPage.html@1:15
    Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'.
    1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'tabRoot' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("s height="100%">
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab1Root" title="Line Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [ERROR ->][tabRoot]="tab2Root" title="Bar Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab3Root" title="Pie Ch"): ng:///AppModule/TabsPage.html@2:15
    Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'.
    1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'tabRoot' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("art"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab2Root" title="Bar Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [ERROR ->][tabRoot]="tab3Root" title="Pie Chart"></super-tab>
    </super-tabs>
    "): ng:///AppModule/TabsPage.html@3:15 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'.
    1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'tabRoot' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<super-tabs height="100%">
        <super-tab [ERROR ->][tabRoot]="tab1Root" title="Line Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab2Root" title="Bar C"): ng:///AppModule/TabsPage.html@1:15
    Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'.
    1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'tabRoot' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("s height="100%">
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab1Root" title="Line Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [ERROR ->][tabRoot]="tab2Root" title="Bar Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab3Root" title="Pie Ch"): ng:///AppModule/TabsPage.html@2:15
    Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'.
    1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'tabRoot' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("art"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab2Root" title="Bar Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [ERROR ->][tabRoot]="tab3Root" title="Pie Chart"></super-tab>
    </super-tabs>
    "): ng:///AppModule/TabsPage.html@3:15
        at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:34999:34)
        at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:45490:19)
        at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59241:39)
        at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59165:62
        at Set.forEach (native)
        at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59165:19)
        at createResult (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59050:19)
        at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8971)
        at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4140)
        at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13731 Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'.
    1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'tabRoot' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<super-tabs height="100%">
        <super-tab [ERROR ->][tabRoot]="tab1Root" title="Line Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab2Root" title="Bar C"): ng:///AppModule/TabsPage.html@1:15
    Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'.
    1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'tabRoot' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("s height="100%">
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab1Root" title="Line Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [ERROR ->][tabRoot]="tab2Root" title="Bar Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab3Root" title="Pie Ch"): ng:///AppModule/TabsPage.html@2:15
    Can't bind to 'tabRoot' since it isn't a known property of 'super-tab'.
    1. If 'super-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'tabRoot' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'super-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("art"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [tabRoot]="tab2Root" title="Bar Chart"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [ERROR ->][tabRoot]="tab3Root" title="Pie Chart"></super-tab>
    </super-tabs>
    "): ng:///AppModule/TabsPage.html@3:15
        at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:34999:34)
        at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:45490:19)
        at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59241:39)
        at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59165:62
        at Set.forEach (native)
        at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59165:19)
        at createResult (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59050:19)
        at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8971)
        at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4140)
        at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13731
```

My Configuration:

> - @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
> - Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
> - @ionic/app-scripts              : 2.0.0
> - @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
> - Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.0
> - Node       : v7.10.0
> - OS         : OS X El Capitan
> - Xcode      : not installed
> - ios-deploy : not installed
> - ios-sim    : not installed
> - npm        : 5.1.0

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: @moh89 That´s the only error i can see

Comment: If i m not wrong it has problem with calling the object of [tab root] which had been call with the object of [super -tab] class

Comment: `import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { BarChartPage } from '../bar-chart/bar-chart';
import { PieChartPage } from '../pie-chart/pie-chart';
import { LineChartPage } from '../line-chart/line-chart';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})

export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = LineChartPage;
  tab2Root = BarChartPage;
  tab3Root = PieChartPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}`

I used the snippet from example. I downgrade ionic2-super-tabs on version 2.6.3 but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the code and it works.

The steps I've taken:

- git clone https://github.com/abritopach/ionic2-d3js-example
- npm install
- ionic serve

My configuration:

- Ionic CLI 3.4.0
- ionic2-super-tabs ^1.1.1
- @ionic/app-scripts: 1.3.0,
- @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular: 1.3.2

I'll try my example with your configuration.

¿Have you been able to run the example?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error.

In https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs/ README say:

"Due to the way this module is designed, some versions of the module might not work with all versios of the Ionic Framework. Refer to the following table to use the appropriate version. Also, some features in the later versions might not be available in the older versions of this module. This page only contains the latest documentation. For older documentation, look up the previous versions of the README.md file using Github.

- Ionic Framework Version  ionic2-super-tabs version
- 3.5.x    3.0.0
- 3.4.x    2.6.3
- 3.0.0    3.3.x
- 2.0.0    2.6.3
- 2.x.x    1.x.x
  "

Steps:

1. Update dependecies in package.json

> ```
>  "ionic-angular": "3.5.0",
>  "ionic2-super-tabs": "3.0.0"
> ```

2. Modify home.html

> ```
> <super-tabs id="mainTabs" selectedTabIndex="0" toolbarColor="light" toolbarBackground="dark" indicatorColor="light"
> ```
>
> badgeColor="light" [config]="{ sideMenu: 'left' }"
>   (tabSelect)="onTabSelect($event)">

3. Modify home.ts

> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>
> ```
> import { BarChartPage } from '../bar-chart/bar-chart';
> import { PieChartPage } from '../pie-chart/pie-chart';
> import { LineChartPage } from '../line-chart/line-chart';
>
> import { SuperTabsController } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';
>
> @Component({
>   templateUrl: 'home.html',
>   providers: [SuperTabsController]
> })
> export class HomePage {
>
>   tab1Root: any = LineChartPage;
>   tab2Root: any = BarChartPage;
>   tab3Root: any = PieChartPage;
>
>   constructor(private superTabsCtrl: SuperTabsController) {
>
>   }
>
>   /*
>   ngAfterViewInit() {
>
>     // must wait for AfterViewInit if you want to modify the tabs instantly
>     this.superTabsCtrl.setBadge('firstPage', 5);
>
>   }
>   */
>
>   hideToolbar() {
>     this.superTabsCtrl.showToolbar(false);
>   }
>
>   showToolbar() {
>     this.superTabsCtrl.showToolbar(true);
>   }
>
>   onTabSelect(ev: any) {
>     console.log('Tab selected', 'Index: ' + ev.index, 'Unique ID: ' + ev.id);
>   }
>
> }
> ```

**My package.json**

```
> ...
> 
>  "dependencies": {
>     "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
>     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
>     "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
>     "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
>     "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
>     "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
>     "d3": "^4.8.0",
>     "ionic-angular": "3.5.0",
>     "ionic2-super-tabs": "3.0.0",
>     "ionicons": "3.0.0",
>     "rxjs": "5.4.0",
>     "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
>     "zone.js": "0.8.12"   },   "devDependencies": {
>     "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.1",
>     "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.2",
>     "@types/d3": "4.7.0",
>     "typescript": "2.3.4"   },
> 
> ...
```